# Forgotten Password in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, forgot-password

I am trying to implement a forgotten password solution in rails.  I have a form for the user to enter the email address for their registered account, and I intend to have a mailer email them a unique URL that will link them to a password reset page.

My **config/routes.rb** file has the following routes:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :lost_password   #the account-email submisison form url
    get :reset_password  #a url for the function that sends the response email
  end
end
```

When I run **rake routes** from the console, I get the paths I want:

```
lost_password_users  GET  /users/lost_password(.:format)  {:action=>"lost_password", :controller=>"users"}
reset_password_users GET  /users/reset_password(.:format) {:action=>"reset_password", :controller=>"users"}
users                GET  /users(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                     POST /users(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
```

BUT! When the user hits the submit button on the form outlined in the code below:

```
<h3>Reset Password</h3>
<%= form_for(:user, :url => reset_password_users_path) do |f| %>
  <p>Enter the email address you used to register for this site.</p></br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>  </br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %> 
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Send Email" %>
  </div> 
<% end %>
```

I get a

> No route matches
>   "/users/reset_password"

error through the ActionController.

I do, in fact, have views and controller functions defined for both the **lost_password_users_path** and the **reset_password_users_path**, so I'm puzzled as to why I would run into this routing error.

I have two questions:

1. Why would the ActionController raise this error, when I clearly have the path, methods, and views defined?
2. Has anyone else implemented a password reset in RoR, and can you lend any insight as to whether or not this approach is good practice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `get :reset_password` to `post :reset_password` in routes.rb

Comment: Thanks, Pravin! Still working through the growing pains of understanding how it all ties together. =P

Answer (score 0):

function of reset password: I hope,it will be work, use in controller update function

```
    if params[:user][:password].present?
    puts "present"
    puts params[:current_password]
    if (params[:user][:password] == "")
      params[:user].delete(:password) 
    else
      if @user.valid_password?(params[:current_password])
        @updated = true
        puts @updated.to_s
        @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        sign_in(@user,:bypass => true) 
        flash[:notice] = "Password Updated Successfully"
        redirect_back fallback_location: user_url
      else
        @updated = false
        puts @updated.to_s
        flash[:danger] = "Current Password does not matched"
        redirect_back fallback_location: user_url

      end
    end
```